# Transaction open for many hours

Tags: .net, vb.net, transactions, timeout, transactionscope

Is there anything wrong with wrapping a process that takes three hours to run in a TransactionScope like this:

```
Dim transactionOptions As TransactionOptions = New TransactionOptions()
Using scope As New TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, transactionOptions)
msgbox("Message Box 1")
scope.complete()
End Using
msgbox("Message Box 2")
```

To get from Message Box 1 to Message Box 2 takes about five hours.

I am sure I tried this in the past with another long running process and the Transaction kept timeing out (I could be wrong), so I committed on each loop.  I read somewhere that you should commit as often as possible.  Is there anything wrong with my approach?

Comment: If you have a transaction that takes five hours to complete you have bigger problems with your design

Comment: @Matt Wilko, what happens if you have a program that loops through one billion records and each one takes x fraction of a second to run? I guess you will say; commit on every loop.

Comment: Firstly you have to question why you are doing that. Add a WHERE clause to reduce the amount of data you are reading. Seconly Reading data should not be part of the transaction, only insert/updates/deletes, so start your transaction just before you do that. You may need to refactor your code to get a list of records to update first before doing the updates.

Comment: @matt wilko, the problem is that every single record has to be updated every week. The logic is too complex to use sql in my opinion. I always use sql to do as much work as is practically possible.

Comment: @W0051977: if you need to update every single record each week, did you consider a "last updated" column, so you can update each record within a transaction? Is it really necessary that all the records update within a single transaction? Maybe we could provide help you with your challenge if you give us more Information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are four basic property.. yeah everyone knows it... Called **ACID**.

Only first one here.

**Atomicity:** So this property says that "In an atomic transaction, a series of database operations either all occur, or nothing occurs."
So, lets say your 5 hour running transaction has 10000 database operations. Do you really want to them occur all (10000 operations) or not at all? In better way, is it possible that you can split in more transactions rather than a single transaction?

Answer (score 1):

How often to commit? Basically the question is: What is YOUR smallest Transaction?

Consider the example of a bank account (very very simplified): you may have 10000 money Transfers from one account to another, but if you Transfer from account A to account B, (let´s say this will be accomplished by two inserts) THIS IS ONE TRANSACTION - commit this one. and then the next one.

Comment: "smallest operation" +1.